# Datepicker not shown when date field added to new tab

Tags: php, datepicker, silverstripe

When I add the date-field to the main content tab, the date-picker is being displayed, but as soon as I change the tab name to i.e. Root.Course the date-picker is not being displayed anymore. Am I missing something?

**Displayed**

```
    $dateFieldFrom = new DateField('course_DateFrom', 'Date from');
    $dateFieldFrom->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
    $dateFieldFrom->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd MMM YYYY');     

    $dateFieldTo = new DateField('course_DateTo', 'Date to');
    $dateFieldTo->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
    $dateFieldTo->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd MMM YYYY');       

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new DateField('course_DateFrom', 'Date from'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new DateField('course_DateTo', 'Date to'));
```

vs

**Not Displayed**

```
    $dateFieldFrom = new DateField('course_DateFrom', 'Date from');
    $dateFieldFrom->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
    $dateFieldFrom->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd MMM YYYY');     

    $dateFieldTo = new DateField('course_DateTo', 'Date to');
    $dateFieldTo->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
    $dateFieldTo->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd MMM YYYY');       

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Course', new DateField('course_DateFrom', 'Date from'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Course', new DateField('course_DateTo', 'Date to'));
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the $dateFieldFrom variable on the $fields->addFieldToTab. You are creating them twice now. Is the $dateFieldFrom added to the Main somewhere else on the code?

Comment: also don't wrap your sample code to unsupported <code> tags as SO has its own wrappers that work just fine :)

Comment: Thank you @OlliTyynelä. By changing it to:  $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Course', $dateFieldFrom);
  $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Course', $dateFieldTo); the datepicker appears :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Course', $dateFieldFrom);
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Course', $dateFieldTo);
```

In the examples above, you configure $dateFieldFrom and $dateFieldTo, but you're adding 2 completely new instances of DateField (without the calendar enabled).